# linux open window on desktop without display manager

Tags: linux, x11, gnome, kde, window-manager

I want to record some video tutorials with record desktop and webcam .
and open webcam with mpv player with this command :

```
mpv av://v4l2:/dev/video2
```

I want to understand how can open webcam without window manager frame in KDE desktop environment ? [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an one-time application, you can right-click the window title bar, and select "More Actions > No Border".

If you want a particular program's window to always be borderless, you could go to System Settings -> Window Management -> Window Rules, and define a rule that will automatically make that window borderless anytime the window is created.

Comment: Wowwww, Thank you men :)

Comment: Can do it with command line ?

Comment: I don't know, I haven't needed to do anything like that from the command line. Perhaps someone else will know?